# Why does the norm element annihilate the class group?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of number fields with $\textrm{Gal}(L/K)=G$. Assume that $\textrm{Cl}(K)$ is trivial. Define the norm element $\mathcal N= \sum_{\sigma \in G} \sigma \in \mathbb Z[G]$. Under the usual action of $\mathbb Z[G]$ on $\textrm{Cl}(L)$, can anybody please explain to me why is it true that $\mathcal N$ annihilates $\textrm{Cl}(L)$?

Comment: I don't know what the usual action of $\mathbb Z[G]$ on $\textrm{Cl}(L)$ is. Could you please explain the usual action of $\mathbb Z[G]$ on $\textrm{Cl}(L)$?

Comment: @NeoTheComputer the natural one $I^{\sum_j n_j \sigma_j} = \prod_j \sigma_j(I)^{n_j}$ where the RHS is a product of fractional ideals

Comment: @reuns Thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: This is not true in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal O_L$ above the prime ideal $p$ of $\mathcal O_K$
then $\mathcal N(P)=p^r\mathcal O_L$ for some integer $r$, and as $p$
is principal, then so is $\mathcal N(P)$. Therefore $\mathcal N(I)$ is principal
for all ideals $I$ of $\mathcal O_L$.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain in more detail why $\mathcal N(P)=p^r \mathcal O_L$? I think this has to do with the fact that galois group acts transitively on the set of prime ideals lying above $p$

Comment: @ShariputraJinasena It's the famous "efg" formula for the decomposition of a prime in an extension field.

Comment: I know the efg formula, but still dont see how that is being used here. Could you please elaborate?